# Navbar overlapping other content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm using Jade for this. My main layout contains the bootstrap navbar.  The file itself is called layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')

    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

  body
    .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
        .container
                .navbar-header
                    a.navbar-brand(href='/') Loc8r
                    button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse',
                    data-target='#navbar-main')
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                #navbar-main.navbar-collapse.collapse
                    ul.nav.navbar-nav
                        li
                            a(href='/about/') About

    .container
        block content

        footer
            .row
                .col-xs-12
                    small &copy; Anon

    script(src='/javascripts/jquery-3.1.1.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.js')
```

The following file is the content that is put into the second .container in the above file.

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 #{title}
    p Welcome to #{title}

    .row.list-group
        .col-xs-12.list-group-item
            h4
                a(href='/location') Location name
                small &nbsp;
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star-empty
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star-empty
                span.badge.pull-right.badge-default distance
            p.address Address here
            p
                span.label.label-warning label
                |   &nbsp;
                span.label.label-warning label
                |   &nbsp;
                span.label.label-warning label
                |   &nbsp;
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-4
            p.lead Loc8r description
```

My style.css file is currently empty.

Thoughts on how I can fix the overlap?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking here. Your navbar is overlapping other content? You're using the bootstrap class `navbar-fixed-top`. This fixes the navbar to the top of the page and overlaps other content because its `z-index: 1030`.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. How can I have a navbar that is both fixed and doesn't overlap other content? @A1raa

Comment: I'm not really sure as to why you would want a navbar fixed to the top of the page that you can't see due to content blocking it. `navbar-fixed-top` means your navigation bar will sit at the top of the page even whilst scrolling. Do you want one that stays attached to the top of the web page and stays there whilst you scroll down content, not attached to the top of the viewport? If this is the case simply remove `navbar-fixed-top` and keep the rest.

Comment: @A1raa Well, I do want the navbar to be fixed at the top while scrolling, but I don't want content on the landing page to be overlapped by the navbar. I guess I need to move this content down.

Comment: @A1raa I'm finding it difficult to explain in this words, and the best example I can think of is the Facebook nav bar. It's fixed to the top, but it doesn't block your content when you land on your home page. It's probably because the content is just positioned lower than the nav bar, but how do I know how much lower my content has to be?

Comment: I see. You can offset the `.container` by the height of your navigation bar. You can give it a `margin-top: 51px` (the default bootstrap navbar height with a 1px border). This should go inside your style.css file. If you don't want to use a `jumbotron` you could give the`.container` an id like `#landingContentContainer`. This should solve your problem but there may be better ways to go about this that I'm sure have been answered on this site. You may have to remove this margin when `navbar-toggle` is active.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div under fixed top bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269611/div-under-fixed-top-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding-top to your content's container (add a class to select that container). This will push the content a little bit lower. For example,

```
.block-content
  padding-top: 60px
```